# SQL Commit in insert script

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, commit

I start with SQL and came across the question: Where and why COMMIT is placed in INSERT SCRIPT?
I consider it inserted at the end to confirm orders. The question stopped me in the fact that I don't know if there are other places in the insert script where it can be placed, is there an article about it or someone would answer me why.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much of the script you want to rollback if there are problems. So you could commit once at the end of the script, and rollback and rerun the script if it fails, or commit after each order so they are saved even if there are problems later in the script. Given the choice, commit early because it frees resources.

Comment: So it's meant to have several transactions
begin
...
commit;
...
begin
...
commit;
and can I return (rollback) at will between them?